# Calling Azure Function ( Queue Trigger) Doesnt work , but it does when i send i message from azure portal

Tags: debugging, .net-core, azure-functions, appsettings, azure-queues

Im working with a personal project with this details: **net core 6 with c# web app and az functions**.
I have a Queue Trigger (Az function) that shows a message and sends an email and I want to call it Queue from an Azure Function.
I'm using the right connection string and Queue name because If I send a message from the azure portal, I see the queue message, I'm able to debug it locally and I also receive an Email.

But when i make the call from my code ( another Az Function) , i see the Queue Message from the portal but i cannot debug it locally and i don't receive the email.

So obviously, it works from the portal but not locally ( or prod), something is wrong with my code.
I'm using this code to make the call from my code:

```
   try
                {
                    string conectionstring = "Myconnection";
                    QueueClient queue = new QueueClient(conectionstring, "myQueueName");
                    var rspqueue = await queue.SendMessageAsync("MyMessage");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw;
                }
```

This show 201 message and i see the message from the azure portal as i said.
Isn't SendMessageAsync supposed to call my Queue Trigger (Az function) ? Or im getting it wrong?

Regards

I tried to call a Queue Trigger (Az function) from another Az Function. I expect to know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

- Well, you are not calling the queue trigger but as the name suggest you are adding messages to the queue and the queue trigger is getting triggered .
- Here I have a  http trigger which is adding the message in the queue.

```
 [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            
            string connectionString = "<Connection String>";
           
            QueueClient queue = new QueueClient(connectionString, "testr");
            
            string message = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World "));
          
            queue.SendMessage(message);
           

            return new OkObjectResult("responseMessage");
        }
```

- My Queue trigger is like this

```
  [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("testr", Connection = "test")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        }
```

- Here I am encoding the string in the http trigger as I am importing a string in the queue trigger.

Queuetrigger output :
[image]

Comment: Thank u so much! this line changed it everything: string message = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World "));  Seems that SendMessage receives a string by parameter but it needs to be formated in UTF8 for xml file.  Regards